# loop flowing steps

Tags: javascript, for-loop, null

This function come from the book "Eloquent Javascript", chapter 3, function.

I don't understand the flowing of the script.

Here is a "for loop" with an impossible mission to make a count value that is equal to 0 and smaller than 0.

At the beginning I expected that it would stop the program but the program is smart. why the impossibility to run the loop doesn't stop the program? 
Here is the snippet:

```
    var power = function (base, exponent) {
    var result = 1;
    for(var count = 0; count < exponent; count ++) {
//repeat as many as needed the self multiplication.
    console.log("count = ", count);
        result *= base;
        console.log(result);

    }
    return result;
};
console.log("finally we get the number ", power(2, 0));
/* A little question with exponent = 0 
Why is that not an error. It is impossible to initiate 
with count = 0 &&  count < exponent.
Weird.*/
```

The output in repl.it

```
    Native Browser JavaScript

finally we get the number  1
```

Comment: Even the program knows it's not possible, so it skip the for loop and return `1`, which is init before the for loop.

Comment: @fuyushimoya Of course but is it possible to understand how?

Comment: The condition part of the for loop, which is `count < exponent`, will be evaluated before enter the statement part, if it is `false`(as 0 < 0 is false), the loop will end and the flow will keep to next statement `return result`. You should check the doc of [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), the init part is only `var count = 0`, and `count < exponent` is not init, but _condition_ to check if the loop can enter its statement part.

Comment: @fuyushimoya
This is a very good response!
count < exponent is a condition to check if the for loop can enter its statement part. Very clear!!! 
If I can say, the for loop is not a native operation, but a two step action: If count < exponent, make the operation, and then increment the count. Very interesting part of programming understanding. where can I learn like this?
''
condition

Comment: [MDN-javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) should be a good place to learn.

Comment: @fuyushimoya
A next time thank you. I think that the for loop is a "masked while loop"!
right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `count < exponent` or rather `0 < 0` is `false`, so the loop doesn't run and it returns the value of `result` when it was defined as `1`:

```
var result = 1;
for(var count = 0; false; count ++) {
    // This doesn't run
}
return result; // So it's still 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to fuyushimoya, I understand:

The first statement in the parenthesis is the initialization of the variable. It is atated anyways before the loop begin. The second statements is  a condition, evaluated before the loop is executed, if this statement boolean value is `true`, the statement inside the loop is executed. after each loop iteration. It change the variable value and then this new value is tested by the second statement and eventually the loop iterates again.

In a case in which the second statement is false at the beginning, the loop doesn't run and the situation is as if we have the first statement alone. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).